# rJava jdk incongruity

Tags: java, r, rstudio, rjava

I'm running Mac High Sierra 10.13.6, R version 3.5.2. I am unable to load my rJava package after installation in the R Console.

In R, running install('rJava') and then library(rJava) returns:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I know that my jdk's should have the same version, so I've made this fix, but for some reason the deleted jdk-11.0.1.jdk keeps popping up in the error message.

Also, I have this written in my .bash_profile:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

which is the same output location when running /usr/libexec/java_home in terminal.

Finally, I've run sudo R CMD javareconf multiple times in terminal. Here's the output from that:

```
Password:  
Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java  
Java version     : 1.8.0_201  
Java home path   :  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre  
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac  
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah  
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar  

trying to compile and link a JNI program   
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include - I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/darwin  
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@5/5.5.0_2/bin/gcc-5 - 
I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../include/darwin  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@5/5.5.0_2/bin/gcc-5 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@5/5.5.0_2/lib -o conftest.so conftest.o -L/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server -ljvm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.


JAVA_HOME        :  
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre  
Java library path: $(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server  
JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/darwin  
JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm  
Updating Java configuration in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources  
Done.
```

Any help would be valuable. Thank you!

Comment: https://zhiyzuo.github.io/installation-rJava/

Comment: @Elliot Frisch, thanks for the link. I had looked at this post earlier, but this time followed everything to a t and it worked out fine.  For anyone else dealing with this problem -- make sure you do every step Zhiya outlines especially using the correct gcc and pointing to the right version in your Makevars doc.